# Calc - Given following characteristics of a function graph, answer the following questions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I haven't taken Calc in a decade and this is for an accounting degree, I think I have the right answers through looking in my old book and for online help, but want to double check

- The function has 3 critical points
- When x=30, the first derivative is negative
- When x=20, the first derivative is zero
- When x=50, the first derivative is zero and the second derivative is positive
- When x=80, the first derivative is zero

Answer the following questions

1. T or F When x=40, the first derivative is positive
2. T or F When x=20 the second derivative is positive
3. T or F When x=12 the first derivative is positive
4. T or F The basic shape of this curve is more like an M than a W
5. T or F For any value of x between 50 and 80, the first derivative will always be negative

I think the answers are F, F, T, T, F.

1. False due to decreasing towards x=50 which is a minimum due to second derivative being positive
2. False due to being a critical point
3. True due to increasing towards x=20, which then decreases until x=50
4. True my graph looks like an M
5. False due to increasing from x=50 which is our minimum towards x=80 which is our 3rd critical point.

Here is the graph I sketched
[image: Plot of function]

Thanks

Comment: I think your answers are correct, although I don't see why the function would be decreasing after $x=80$.

Comment: @Jay they all seem right. My only critique would be on your explanation of the second question. A critical point can have a positive 2nd derivative, but what type of critical point does it have to be and why can't it be that type of critical point based on the given info?

Comment: Youre correct ,but the correct reason for 2 being F is because the first derivative at 30 is -ve

Comment: @AlexLostado  Good point, I think I was going off the assumption that critical point often, but not always means a change in increasing/decreasing

Comment: @pranavB23 Good catch, I misread and thought it was first derivative. 

So since increasing/decreasing only changes at critical points and there is no critical point between 20 and 30 we know it is decreasing at 30, so does that make 20 a local max, which means it's second derivative has to be negative right?  

But now I'm questioning myself about 3.  How do I actually know it is increasing x=12?  A critical point doesn't have to be a change in increasing/decreasing, right? So doesn't mean it has to go increasing to decreasing at x=20, right?

Comment: @Jay You're correct we do not have information to show that the function is increasing at x = 12 .The critical point at 12 might be a maxima or a point of inflection. So we can only guess without additonal information

Comment: @pranavB23 Do you think I should email my processor asking if there is more info?  I know x=20 can't be a min, but it could be a max or just a critical point where there is no change like x^3

Comment: @Jay Perhaps you should.